# Checked vs unchecked exceptions code reusability

Tags: exception

I want to know why my program is behaving this way.

I have a method that throws an ArithmeticException when trying to divide by zero. I put this method in a *try* block. When it throws an exception, if at all, the proceeding catch block will catch this ArithmeticException.

I understand this part 100%.

But I did a bit of experimenting. In my method body:

```
public static int quotient(int number1, int number2) {
    if (number2 == 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Divisor cannot be zero!");
    return number1 / number2;
}
```

I removed the third line. When I removed the third line, the program still ran fine and performed exactly as it did before. It still caught the ArithmeticException error when it occurred.

Is it because ArithmeticException is an **unchecked** exception and this error is caught only during runtime, thus negating the need for me to specifically declare that this program will cause an unchecked exception? If it was a checked exception, would I specifically need to declare that this method will throw an unchecked exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated Arithmetic exception is a runtime exception, you do not need to specify that it throws an exception.

Although you do need to specify if your program throws a compile time exception using a throws statement. One example where you need to check the exception would be an IOException.

Comment: thanks one more thing if you know, do you know what it means to "rethrow the exception to the caller?" ?

Comment: you rethrow an exception so that you don't have to write multiple catch blocks. Instead of handling the exception at the source, you can throw the excpeption to the caller and handle it in another class.

Comment: sorry to be stupid, but what do you mean by caller? Can you be more specific and then I'll mark you as answered thanks

Comment: All good. The caller is the method which is being excecuted, for example the caller in your example would be the method: quotient. say you include this method in another class, instead of the exception being thrown in the quotient class, it could be handled in the class that is calling the method. When you have hundreds of methods, each with exceptions, throwing exceptions to the caller allows you to deal with the exceptions in one or fewer locations as necessary.